# Content raw packet

Tags: c, сеть, c++

Добрый день, уважаемые.

Помогите разобраться с содержимым TCP/IP пакетов. Дело в том, что собранные по-разному пакеты действительно имеют разное содержание, однако в теории должны быть сходными. После успешной сборки, в обоих случаях, пакеты отправляются в сеть (с ноутбука на ближайший роутер) средствами Packet32.lib (from Qt).
Факт различия установлен моей же скромной утилиткой, которая парсит все входящие/исходящие пакеты с сетевой карты выбранного интерфейса. Также я написал маленький парсер для по инструкции собранных пакетов, лог которой далее будет прикреплен.

*заранее прошу прощения за недостаточно красивый код. Сначала уж хочу, чтобы там всё заработало и уж затем красота. Ну и обилие перепробованного мною внесло свою лепту.

---

Вот так я собираю пакет не по инструкции, а по наитию:

```
unsigned char* Packet::u_charPacket()
{
    unsigned char *packetbuff = new unsigned char[1024];

    /* Fill the rest of the packet */
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        packetbuff[i] = i%256;

    //destinations mac-adress
    packetbuff[0] = 0x74;
    packetbuff[1] = 0xEA;
    packetbuff[2] = 0x3A;
    packetbuff[3] = 0xD7;
    packetbuff[4] = 0x84;
    packetbuff[5] = 0x12;

    //source mac-adress
    packetbuff[6] = 0x00;
    packetbuff[7] = 0x16;
    packetbuff[8] = 0x17;
    packetbuff[9] = 0xD8;
    packetbuff[10] = 0x76;
    packetbuff[11] = 0x53;

    // Длина, либо тип кадра. В нашем случае – это тип кадра. Кадр Ethernet II.
    packetbuff[12]=0x08;
    packetbuff[13]=0x00;

    // ПОРТ ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ
    packetbuff[14]=0x00;
    packetbuff[15]=0xFF;

    // ПОРТ ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ
    packetbuff[16]=0x3A;
    packetbuff[17]=0xCB;

    // Размер аппаратного адреса. Размер адреса в байтах, содержащегося в полях аппаратного адреса
    // отправителя и аппаратного адреса назначения. Размер аппаратных адресов Ethernet равен 6.
    packetbuff[18]=0x06;

    // Размер адреса протокола. Указывает размер адресов протокола в байтах, размещенных в полях
    // адреса протокола отправителя и адреса протокола назначения. IP-адреса всегда состоят из 4 байтов.
    packetbuff[19]=0x04;

    // Код операции. Описывает тип сообщения, переносимого пакетом. Допустимые варианты перечисляются ниже.
    // 1 - ARP Request (ARP-запрос).    2 - ARP Reply (ARP-ответ).
    // 3 - RARP Request (RARP-запрос).  4 - RARP Reply (RARP-ответ).
    packetbuff[20]=0x00;
    packetbuff[21]=0x01;

    // Аппаратный адрес отправителя. Длина определяется значением поля размера аппаратного адреса.
    // Содержит аппаратный (то есть Ethernet) адрес системы, посылающей сообщение, как в случае
    // запроса (request), так и в случае ответа (reply).
    packetbuff[22]=packetbuff[6];
    packetbuff[23]=packetbuff[7];
    packetbuff[24]=packetbuff[8];
    packetbuff[25]=packetbuff[9];
    packetbuff[26]=packetbuff[10];
    packetbuff[27]=packetbuff[11];

    // Адрес протокола отправителя. Длина определяется значением поля размера адреса протокола.
    // Представляет собой адрес по протоколу (то есть IP) системы, посылающей сообщение, как в случае
    // запроса (request), так и в случае ответа (reply).
    packetbuff[28]=0x01;
    packetbuff[29]=0x64;

    // IP-АДРЕС ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ
    packetbuff[30]=0xC0;
    packetbuff[31]=0xA8;
    packetbuff[32]=0x01;
    packetbuff[33]=0x01;

    packetbuff[34]=0x00;
    packetbuff[35]=0x00;
    packetbuff[36]=0x00;
    packetbuff[37]=0x00;

    // IP-АДРЕС ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ
    packetbuff[38]=0xC0;
    packetbuff[39]=0xA8;
    packetbuff[40]=0x01;
    packetbuff[41]=0x01;

    return packetbuff;
}
```

---

Вкратце, вот так отправляю:

```
...
if ((lpPacket = PacketAllocatePacket()) == NULL) {
        printf("\nError:failed to allocate the LPPACKET structure.");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
...
unsigned char *packet;
packet = u_charPacket();

//unsigned char packet[1024];
//constructPacket(packet);
...
PacketInitPacket(lpPacket, packet, sizeof(packet));
...
if(PacketSetNumWrites(lpAdapter,npacks)==FALSE)
        printf("Warning: Unable to send more than one packet in a single write!\n");
...
if(PacketSendPacket(lpAdapter,lpPacket,TRUE)==FALSE)
    {
        printf("Error sending the packets!\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
...
```

---

На выходе имеем:

```
14:06:44,028614 len:1024
192.168.1.100:255 -> 192.168.1.1:15051
10717320
```

---

Это получается вот так:

```
//Выводим время захвата пакета, время поступления кадра, длину данного пакета
printf("%s,%.6d len:%d\n", timestr, header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);
...
/* print ip addresses and ports */
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d:%d -> %d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n",
        ih->saddr.byte1,
        ih->saddr.byte2,
        ih->saddr.byte3,
        ih->saddr.byte4,
        sport,
        ih->daddr.byte1,
        ih->daddr.byte2,
        ih->daddr.byte3,
        ih->daddr.byte4,
        dport);
    printf("%d\n", pkt_data);
```

---

Всё как и задумывалось. А далее покажу как я собираю пакет по инструкции:

```
void Packet::constructPacket(unsigned char* packet)
{
    eth_header *ethhdr;
    ip_header *iphdr;
    tcp_header *tcphdr;

    p_header pseudo_header;

    char *dump = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    DeviceInfo devInfo = getAdapterInfo(chosenDevice);
    printMacAddress(devInfo.PhysicalAddress);

    // *******************  Ethernet Header *****************
    ethhdr = (peth_header)packet;

    memcpy(ethhdr->src, devInfo.PhysicalAddress , 6); //Source Mac address
    memcpy(ethhdr->dst, devInfo.GatewayPhysicalAddress, 6); //Destination MAC address
    ethhdr->type = htons(0x0800); //IP Frames

    // *******************  IP Header *****************
    iphdr = (pip_header)(packet + sizeof(eth_header));

    iphdr->ip_version = 4;
    iphdr->ip_header_len = 5;   //In double words thats 4 bytes
    iphdr->ip_tos = 0;
    iphdr->ip_total_length = htons (sizeof(ip_header) + sizeof(tcp_header) + strlen(dump));
    iphdr->ip_id = htons(2);
    iphdr->ip_frag_offset = 0;
    iphdr->ip_reserved_zero=0;
    iphdr->ip_dont_fragment=1;
    iphdr->ip_more_fragment=0;
    iphdr->ip_frag_offset1 = 0;
    iphdr->ip_ttl    = 64;
    iphdr->ip_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iphdr->ip_srcaddr  = devInfo.IP;
    iphdr->ip_destaddr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
    iphdr->ip_checksum =0;
    iphdr->ip_checksum = in_checksum((unsigned short*)iphdr, sizeof(ip_header));

    // *******************  TCP Header *****************
    tcphdr = (ptcp_header)(packet + sizeof(eth_header) + sizeof(ip_header));

    tcphdr->source_port = htons( 255 );
    tcphdr->dest_port = htons(15051);
    tcphdr->sequence=0;
    tcphdr->acknowledge=0;
    tcphdr->reserved_part1=0;
    tcphdr->data_offset=5;
    tcphdr->fin=0;
    tcphdr->syn=1;
    tcphdr->rst=0;
    tcphdr->psh=0;
    tcphdr->ack=0;
    tcphdr->urg=0;
    tcphdr->ecn=0;
    tcphdr->cwr=0;
    tcphdr->window = htons(64240);
    tcphdr->checksum=0;
    //tcphdr->checksum = in_checksum((unsigned short*)tcphdr, sizeof(tcp_header));
    tcphdr->urgent_pointer = 0;

    // *******************  Data Dump *****************
    char *data = (char*)(packet + sizeof(eth_header) + sizeof(ip_header) + sizeof(tcp_header));
    strcpy(data,dump);

    // *******************  Checksum calculation *****************
    pseudo_header.source_address = devInfo.IP;
    pseudo_header.dest_address = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
    pseudo_header.placeholder = 0;
    pseudo_header.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    pseudo_header.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(tcp_header) + strlen(dump));
    memcpy(&pseudo_header.tcp , tcphdr , sizeof tcp_header);

    unsigned char *seudo;
    seudo = new unsigned char(sizeof(p_header) + strlen(dump));
    memcpy(seudo, &pseudo_header, sizeof p_header);
    memcpy(seudo + sizeof(p_header), data, strlen(dump));

    tcphdr->checksum = in_checksum((unsigned short*)seudo, sizeof(p_header) + strlen(dump));
}
```

---

Результат совершенно не сходится с ожидаемым.
На выходе имеем:

```
15:02:17,655748 len:1024
58.0.40.126:0 -> 174.119.0.0:0
7107620
```

---

И ещё вот так можно посмотреть на содержимое ещё не отправленного пакета:

```
***********************TCP Packet*************************

Ethernet Header
 |-Destination Address : 74-EA-3A-D7-84-12 
 |-Source Address      : 00-16-17-D8-76-53 
 |-Protocol            : 0x0800

IP Header
 |-IP Version : 4
 |-IP Header Length : 5 DWORDS or 20 Bytes
 |-Type Of Service : 0
 |-IP Total Length : 66 Bytes(Size of Packet)
 |-Identification : 2
 |-Reserved ZERO Field : 0
 |-Dont Fragment Field : 1
 |-More Fragment Field : 0
 |-TTL : 64
 |-Protocol : 6
 |-Checksum : 46846
 |-Source IP : 192.168.1.100
 |-Destination IP : 192.168.1.1

TCP Header
 |-Source Port : 255
 |-Destination Port : 15051
 |-Sequence Number : 0
 |-Acknowledge Number : 0
 |-Header Length : 5 DWORDS or 20 BYTES
 |-CWR Flag : 0
 |-ECN Flag : 0
 |-Urgent Flag : 0
 |-Acknowledgement Flag : 0
 |-Push Flag : 0
 |-Reset Flag : 0
 |-Synchronise Flag : 1
 |-Finish Flag : 0
 |-Window : 64240
 |-Checksum : 2142
 |-Urgent Pointer : 0

 DATA Dump 
IP Header
 45 00 00 42 00 02 40 00 40 06 b6 fe c0 a8 01 64          E..B..@.@......d 
 c0 a8 01 01                                              ....

TCP Header
 00 ff 3a cb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 02 fa f0          ..:.........P... 
 08 5e 00 00                                              .^..

Data Payload
 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP 
 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 00 00 00 00 00 00          QRSTUVWXYZ...... 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ................ 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 53 59 53 54 45 4d          ..........SYSTEM 
 5c 43 75 72 72 65 6e 74 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 53          \CurrentControlS 
 65 74 5c 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 5c 4e 50 46 00          et\Services\NPF. 
 00 00 00 e0 fd 7e 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0          .....~.......... 
 fd 7e 00 00 00 00 b0 f9 3a 00 c4 eb 5a 6c 6c 46          .~......:...ZllF 
 4d 00 78 3d 4c 00 af 2c ae 77 58 3d 4c 00 00 00          M.x=L..,.wX=L... 
 00 00 d3 3c ae 77 84 f7 3a 77 a0 16 d9 75 00 00          ...<.w..:w...u.. 
 00 00 00 00 48 00 50 01 48 00 01 00 00 00 01 00          ....H.P.H....... 
 00 00 00 00 48 00 50 3d 4c 00 00 00 00 00 00 01          ....H.P=L....... 
 09 08 01 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 50 01 48 00 05 00          ..........P.H... 
 00 00 68 62 4c 00 10 fa 3a 00 00 fb 3a 00 b7 35          ..hbL...:...:..5 
 ae 77 00 00 48 00 78 3d 4c 00 d0 fa 3a 00 aa 38          .w..H.x=L...:..8 
 ae 77 10 f6 3a 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 58 3d          .w..:w......H.X= 
 4c 00 07 00 00 07 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0f 00          L............... 
 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 58 d6 4b 00 50 01          ..Ђ.......X.K.P. 
 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 0b 03 10 00 11 00          H.......H....... 
 00 00 58 3d 4c 00 50 01 48 00 02 00 00 02 00 00          ..X=L.P.H....... 
 00 00 07 00 00 07 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 23 c4 f9          .............#.. 
 3a 00 03 00 00 00 54 fb 3a 00 05 00 00 00 07 00          :.....T.:....... 
 00 00 fe ff ff ff 2f 1a 08 3d 05 00 00 00 0f 00          ....../..=...... 
 00 00 68 62 4c 00 52 3d 4c 00 50 3d 4c 00 d0 e1          ..hbL.R=L.P=L... 
 b1 77 74 01 48 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 48 00 58 3d          .wt.H.....P.H.X= 
 4c 00 50 3d 4c 00 58 3d 4c 00 58 d6 4b 00 21 f9          L.P=L.X=L.X.K.!. 
 ac 77 8f d1 d5 75 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          .w...u ......... 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c fb 3a 00 78 25 00 00 88 fb          ........:.x%.... 
 3a 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 d1 d5 75 a1 6d          :............u.m 
 63 16 00 00 00 00 78 25 00 00 00 e0 fd 7e 00 00          c.....x%.....~.. 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 fc fa 3a 00 58 3d 4c 00 b4 fb          ........:.X=L... 
 3a 00 f0 6f d8 75 55 11 81 63 fe ff ff ff e0 d1          :..o.uU..c...... 
 d5 75 37 32 eb 76 20 01 00 00 78 25 00 00 88 fb          .u72.v ...x%.... 
 3a 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84 fb          :............... 
 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 98 fb 3a 00 26 42          :...........:.&B 
 0f 00 20 01 00 00 78 25 00 00 88 fb 3a 00 04 00          .. ...x%....:... 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84 fb 3a 00 00 00          ............:... 
 00 00 c8 34 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 d0 07 00 08 f8          ...4%........... 
 4b 00 fe ff ff ff a8 42 4d 00                            K......BM.

###########################################################
```

---

Ну и в чём может быть ошибка? Хотелось бы, чтобы пакет, представленный во втором случае, отправлялся корректно. Что же для этого сделать? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Предоставлю дополнительную информацию, если необходимо. Помимо обозначенного вопроса, приму в дар готовый и рабочий механизм.

P.P.S. В скором времени сам отвечу на свой вопрос, если это кому-то интересно. Либо просто удалю. Вроде бы нашёл должные ответы.

Comment: @Allow, как-то очень сложно разобраться, что именно Вы делаете (какая печать к какому коду относится и где чем именно печатаете).

Я правильно понимаю, что в первой части кода Вы формируете пакет,  
а затем отправляете **именно этот пакет** и перехватываете **его же**, затем печатаете, получая текст

    .... len:1024
    192.168.1.100:255 -> 192.168.1.1:15051
    ....

А во второй части аналогичные действия приводят к неожиданной Вашей печати, но дамп тот, что Вы формировали?

--

А что Вам на самом деле хочется сделать? Из каких параметров Вы хотите собрать и отправить пакет?

Comment: Извините, я старался оформить всё понятным образом. Мне кажется я уже близок к решению данной проблемы. Начитался.

По существу. На счёт 1ой части всё так, как вы описали.
Во 2ой части я формирую всё тот же пакет (теоретически), но с помощью стандартных структур.

__
На самом деле мне нужно написать утилиту, которая бы отправляла максимально быстро крупный объем данных. Причём на основе библиотеки winpcap/libpcap.

Comment: @Allow, если я правильно понимаю, то приведенный дамп (и инфа перед ним) это данные пакета, который Вы делаете по варианту 2. В этом случае все ОК (dest-ip, port, TTL ...) все совпадает с тем, что Вы в коде пишете в создаваемый пакет.

Т.е. проблема в *Вашей печати*. Может просто не те аргументы в свою функцию печати передаете (такая вот дурацкая описка)?

--

Ну, а мне из приведенного тут кода всю цепочку вызовов и передачи параметров просто не видно.